# How to simplify the use of too many IF statements when finding specific cases

Tags: java, simplify

I have code which a user will select different perameters from 5 dropdown menus, these can be: "None", 'Name', 'Manager', 'AccessLevel', 'Inhabitant' and 'Location' these will be matched with jtextfields that are searched to get the inputed value. However to get these values i am basically do alot of if statements to determine the combination of values e.g. Name, Manager and Location together will give the SQL statement:
`query = "SELECT * FROM propertyInfo WHERE propertyName = ? AND propertyManager = ? AND propertyLocation = ?";`

this leads to a convoluted mess of if statements, is there any way to simplify it?

it works however to actually create it i would have to do hundreds of lines for different combinations and it will be hard to expand later. however this is some of my current code:

```
`if (searchingForName == true) {
          if (searchingForManager == true) {
              if (searchingForAccessLevel == true) { // final lvl 1
                   query = "SELECT * FROM propertyInfo WHERE propertyName = ? AND propertyManager = ? AND accessLevelRequired = ?"; 
                   query2 = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS recordCount FROM propertyInfo WHERE  propertyName = ? AND propertyManager = ? AND accessLevelRequired = ?"; 
              }else if ((searchType1.equals("Inhabitant") || searchType2.equals("Inhabitant") || searchType3.equals("Inhabitant"))) { // final lvl 2
                query = "SELECT * FROM propertyInfo WHERE propertyName = ? AND propertyManager = ? AND propertyInhabitant = ?"; 
                query2 = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS recordCount FROM propertyInfo WHERE  propertyName = ? AND propertyManager = ? AND propertyInhabitant = ?"; 
            }else if ((searchType1.equals("Location") || searchType2.equals("Location") || searchType3.equals("Location"))) { // finaly lvl 3
                query = "SELECT * FROM propertyInfo WHERE propertyName = ? AND propertyManager = ? AND propertyLocation = ?"; 
                query2 = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS recordCount FROM propertyInfo WHERE  propertyName = ? AND propertyManager = ? AND propertyLocation = ?"; 
            }
          }  else if ((searchType1.equals("AccessLevel") || searchType2.equals("AccessLevel") || searchType3.equals("AccessLevel"))) { // sub lvl 2
               if ((searchType1.equals("Inhabitant") || searchType2.equals("Inhabitant") || searchType3.equals("Inhabitant"))) { //final lvl 1
                query = "SELECT * FROM propertyInfo WHERE propertyName = ? AND accessLevelRequired = ? AND propertyInhabitant = ?"; 
                query2 = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS recordCount FROM propertyInfo WHERE  propertyName = ? AND accessLevelRequired = ? AND propertyInhabitant = ?"; 
            }else if ((searchType1.equals("Location") || searchType2.equals("Location") || searchType3.equals("Location"))) { // final lvl 2
                query = "SELECT * FROM propertyInfo WHERE propertyName = ? AND accessLevelRequired = ? AND propertyLocation = ?"; 
                query2 = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS recordCount FROM propertyInfo WHERE  propertyName = ? AND accessLevelRequired = ? AND propertyLocation = ?"; 
            }
          } else if ((searchType1.equals("Inhabitant") || searchType2.equals("Inhabitant") || searchType3.equals("Inhabitant"))) { // sub lvl 3
               if ((searchType1.equals("Location") || searchType2.equals("Location") || searchType3.equals("Location"))) { // final lvl 1
                query = "SELECT * FROM propertyInfo WHERE propertyName = ? AND propertyInhabitant = ? AND propertyLocation = ?"; 
                query2 = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS recordCount FROM propertyInfo WHERE  propertyName = ? AND propertyInhabitant = ? AND propertyLocation = ?"; 
          }
               
      //}
      }else if ((searchType1.equals("Manager") || searchType2.equals("Manager") || searchType3.equals("Manager"))) { // main lvl 2
          
          
          if ((searchType1.equals("AccessLevel") || searchType2.equals("AccessLevel") || searchType3.equals("AccessLevel"))) { // sub lvl 1
              
              
            if ((searchType1.equals("Inhabitant") || searchType2.equals("Inhabitant") || searchType3.equals("Inhabitant"))) {// final lvl 1
                   query = "SELECT * FROM propertyInfo WHERE propertyManager = ? AND accessLevelRequired = ? AND propertyInhabitant = ?"; 
                   query2 = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS recordCount FROM propertyInfo WHERE   propertyManager = ? AND accessLevelRequired = ? AND propertyInhabitant = ?"; 
                   
            }else if ((searchType1.equals("Location") || searchType2.equals("Location") || searchType3.equals("Location"))) { // final lvl 2
                query = "SELECT * FROM propertyInfo WHERE propertyManager = ? AND accessLevelRequired = ? AND propertyLocation = ?"; 
                query2 = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS recordCount FROM propertyInfo WHERE  propertyManager = ? AND accessLevelRequired = ? AND propertyLocation = ?"; 
            }
          }  else if ((searchType1.equals("Inhabitant") || searchType2.equals("Inhabitant") || searchType3.equals("Inhabitant"))) { // sub lvl 2
                if ((searchType1.equals("Location") || searchType2.equals("Location") || searchType3.equals("Location"))) { // final lvl 1
                query = "SELECT * FROM propertyInfo WHERE propertyManager = ? AND propertyInhabitant = ? AND propertyLocation = ?"; 
                query2 = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS recordCount FROM propertyInfo WHERE  propertyManager = ? AND propertyInhabitant = ? AND propertyLocation = ?"; 
            }
          }
        `  } 
      }
```

Comment: you could try reversing if elses as in https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/47789/how-would-you-refactor-nested-if-statements

Comment: https://xyproblem.info/ Provide the problem itself.

Comment: Have you tried building the prepared statement dynamically based on the conditions you have?

Comment: Unrelated, but never do `if (foo == true) {` and instead always do `if (foo) {`. It's just cleaner and less risky.

Answer (score 2):

You can simplify this process by dynamically constructing the SQL query based on the selected parameters. Here's a more structured approach:

```
// Define the base query
String query = "SELECT * FROM propertyInfo WHERE 1 = 1";

// Initialize a list to store query parameters
List<Object> parameters = new ArrayList<>();

// Check if Name is selected
if (searchingForName) {
    query += " AND propertyName = ?";
    parameters.add(nameValue);
}

// Check if Manager is selected
if (searchingForManager) {
    query += " AND propertyManager = ?";
    parameters.add(managerValue);
}

// Check if AccessLevel is selected
if (searchingForAccessLevel) {
    query += " AND accessLevelRequired = ?";
    parameters.add(accessLevelValue);
}

// Check if Inhabitant is selected
if (searchingForInhabitant) {
    query += " AND propertyInhabitant = ?";
    parameters.add(inhabitantValue);
}

// Check if Location is selected
if (searchingForLocation) {
    query += " AND propertyLocation = ?";
    parameters.add(locationValue);
}
```

For each selected parameter (e.g., Name, Manager, etc.), you dynamically add a corresponding condition to the query string and add the parameter value to the ***parameters*** list. Finally, you can execute the query using a prepared statement with the parameters.

Have a good one!

Comment: That code looks really good, and is what im looking for, but the issue is that i dont know how arraylists work and how to take the output from this into the actual code, can you please link an article so i can learn about arraylists?

Comment: @ThomasHumphreys  It's not a tutorial, but Oracle has the APIs for Classes and Interfaces online.  Check out the [ArrayList API](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ArrayList.html) . If you want to find tutorials, you can [Google for them](https://www.google.com/search?q=java+arraylist+tutorial&oq=java+arraylist+tutorial)

Comment: @ThomasHumphreys, here is the _Java_ tutorial on the _Collections Framework_, which includes the _ArrayList_ class.  _[Trail: Collections (The Java™ Tutorials)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/index.html)_